# Google Drive API "Post" Method, uploading an image file with meta data, Python

Tags: python, python-requests, upload, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload an image file with meta data in Python.

I know there's a very convenient Python API, but I want to use "Post" Method so that I can use "aiohttp" with it.

After reading the official documents, I coded as below and got 400 error.

What's going wrong with it?

```
import requests
import json
import sys

with open('storage.json', 'r') as file:
    token = json.load(file)
    token = token["access_token"]

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files'
file_metadata = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'name': 'test.jpg',
    'parents': [],
    'mimeType': None
}
media = {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    'file': open('test2.jpg', 'rb'),
}
data = {
    'MetaData': file_metadata,
    'Media': media,
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token),
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/related',
    'Content-Length': str(sys.getsizeof(data)),
}
params = {
    'uploadType': 'multipart'
}

res = requests.post(url, data=data, params=params, headers=headers)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
import requests
import json

with open('storage.json', 'r') as file:
    token = json.load(file)
    token = token["access_token"]

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files"
file_metadata = {"name": "test.jpg"}
data = {
    "MetaData": (
        "metadata",
        json.dumps(file_metadata),
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    ),
    "Media": open("test2.jpg", "rb"),
}

headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token) }
params = {"uploadType": "multipart"}

res = requests.post(url, files=data, params=params, headers=headers)
print(res.text)
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is returned.

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "###",
 "name": "test.jpg",
 "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
}
```

In this case, the file is uploaded to the root folder. When you want to put the file to the specific folder, please add `'parents': ['###folderId###']` to `file_metadata`.

#### Reference:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)

Answer (score 1):

I think,You are about to reach your destination,just change the data parameter into json meaning use `json = data` instead of `data = data`

```
import requests
import json
import sys

with open('storage.json', 'r') as file:
    token = json.load(file)
    token = token["access_token"]

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files'
file_metadata = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'name': 'test.jpg',
    'parents': [],
    'mimeType': None
}
media = {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    'file': open('test2.jpg', 'rb'),
}
data = {
    'MetaData': file_metadata,
    'Media': media,
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token),
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/related',
    'Content-Length': str(sys.getsizeof(data)),
}
params = {
    'uploadType': 'multipart'
}

res = requests.post(url, json=data, params=params, headers=headers)
print(res)
```